# Can't save or apply changes in articles

Tags: joomla3.5

Im running a few issues in my Joomla site. All of them are related with Joomla articles.

- After saving articles the changes don't apply and the page doesn't stop loading...
- If I create a new article and save it seems to be fine but If I get into the article the title and content don't come up. Its absolutly empty.
- After trash an article I get the following warning: "null primary key not allowed"

I've tried the following to frigure it out:

- Reinstall Joomla core Files
- Turned on Joomla Debug to see errors and Turned off some plugins
- Fix Database

Any idea about it?
The site is running the latest Joomla 3.6.2

Comment: Have you checked the browser console to see if there are JavaScript errors?